# Getting value from multidimensional array by key in laravel 5.4 blade

Tags: arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-blade

I met some difficulties when I was trying to get value from an array in my php blade.
It has rather clear structure (printed with dd function)

```
{{dd($attr)}}

array:4 [▼
  "id" => "215"
  "type" => "select"
  "name" => "Status"
  "value" => array:2 [▼
    "pred" => array:3 [▼
      0 => "Employed"
      1 => "On vacation"
      2 => "Dismissed"
    ]
    "sel_val" => "0"
  ]
]
```

And when I want to get a value by key 'sel_val' or 'pred'

```
print_r($attr['value']['pred']);
```

it gives me Illegal string offset 'pred'

And it works nice in Controller. What should i do?

Comment: is this working print_r($attr['value']['sel_val']); ?

Comment: Are you passing attr variable to view?

Comment: Can you show your blade file and `return` statement of controller.

Answer (score 0):

It gives that error because `pred` is also an array. you'll have to do `$attr['value']['pred'][0]` to get `Employed`, `$attr['value']['pred'][1]` to get `On vacation`, `$attr['value']['pred'][2]` to get `Dismissed` and `$attr['value']['sel_val']` to get the value of `sel_val` which is `0` in this case. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

working fine when we send array in compact function in the controller

```
$record = array('id' => '215', 'type' => 'select', 'value' => array('pred' => array('0'=> 'Employed', '1' => 'On vacation', '2' => 'Dismissed'),'sel_val' => '0'));

return view('home', compact('record'));
```